# asp.net mvc routing routelink creating route defined first in application.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to MVC and little confused with routing. I have defined 2 routes as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "testingController1",
    " /mobile/{controller}/{action}/{key}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Home" });

routes.MapRoute(
    "testingController2",
    "/desktop/{controller}/{action}/{key}",
     defaults: new { controller = " Controller2", action = "Home" });
```

As seen above I have 2 routes. Now on using a route link for “testingController2” with Controller=” Controller2”, Action =”Products” the url is redirected rendered in html is /Mobile/Controller2/Products. How to resolve the above issue. I want it to be rendered as /desktop not Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have implemented, to test you will have to call the url like:
/desktop/testingController2/Products/

Another way to do what you did could be using the concept of Areas. Please take a look at this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) and take a look at the steps 13 and 14 on how to register areas.

Unless there is a special requirement to do what you did, you could just leave the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home",
         action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

And then create a controller called MobileController and another called desktopController.
By then adding Actions called Products you would be able to use the links such as: 
www.yoursite.com/mobile/products 
www.yoursite.com/desktop/products